# Change ph@user:~$ to muxx@user:~$

Tags: users, username

A software engineer used `hp` as username while installing Ubuntu on my device, and I want to change it to my name but all efforts have proved fruitless.

current state:

```
hp@phavor-george:~$
```

I want to change the hp part to my name, for example

```
muxx@phavor-george:~$
```

Comment: settings > details > users > unlock > change username > save & lock

Comment: Since this is a new installation, IMO the best way is to create a new user with root's (administrator's) privileges. Then use it for few days to be sure everything works as it is expected and delete the `hp` user.